# React Native Alert : comparison between items in flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am currently doing a project where I can insert item exam in a flatlist and each item have its own id , mark and grade . I am expecting the program to output an alert after I add new exam in the flatlist where if the mark of new exam is lower than the previous, it will alert saying " your current mark is lower than previous exam"

this is the example of my expectation:
first item is Mid Term Exam (90 marks, grade A) . then I add Final Exam( 70 marks, grade B) . after press add button , it will alert " your current mark is lower than previous exam".

this is my code for the item in the flatlist:

```
const ListItem = ({exam}) => {

        return <View style={ styles.listItem }>
          <View style={styles.subject}>
            <View>
              <Text style={[styles.examText , {fontSize: 18}]}>
            {exam?.Term}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.subjectMarkGrade}>
              <Text style={[styles.examText , {width: '50%'}]}>
              Mark: {exam?.Mark} ( {exam?.Grade} )
              </Text>
            </View>

          </View>
          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.delete ]} onPress={() => deleteExam(exam?.id)}>
              <Icon name="remove" size={15} color={'#fff'} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>;
};

return (
<View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={styles.ExamWrapper}>
                    <FlatList
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                        contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 10 , paddingBottom: 100}}
                        data={exam}
                        keyExtractor = { (item) => item.id.toString() }
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem exam={item}/>}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.typeMsgContainer}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TextInput
                style={[styles.typeMsgBox , {width: '50%' , borderBottomWidth: 0 , borderTopLeftRadius: 30,}]}
                placeholder={'Add Exam Term...'}
                value={termInput}
                onChangeText={(text) => setTermInput(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={[styles.typeMsgBox , {width: '25%' , borderBottomWidth: 0 , borderTopLeftRadius: 0}]}
                placeholder={'Add Marks'}
                keyboardType= "numeric"
                value={markInput}
                onChangeText={(text) => setMarkInput(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={[styles.typeMsgBox , {width: '25%' , borderBottomWidth: 0 , borderTopLeftRadius: 0 , borderTopRightRadius: 10,}]}
                placeholder={'Add Grades'}
                value={gradeInput}
                onChangeText={(text) => setGradeInput(text)}
            />
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff' , borderColor: '#4169E1' , borderWidth: 1 , borderTopWidth:0, borderBottomRightRadius: 10,}}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendBtn} onPress={addExam}>
            <View >
                <Icon name="add" size={30} color="white"/>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>
);
```

this is the addExam() :

```
const addExam = (subject) => {
        if (termInput === '' || markInput === '' || gradeInput === ''){
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill in all box');
        } else {
          const newExam = {
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            Term: termInput,
            Mark: markInput,
            Grade: gradeInput,
          };
          setExam([...exam,newExam]);
          setTermInput('');
          setMarkInput('');
          setGradeInput('');
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addExam function you can take the last item in your list and do a comparison to the new item being added.

```
const addExam = (newExamItem) => {
  const prevExam = // get the last item in your list. you can keep your list of items in a state
  if (newExamItem.mark < prevExam.mark){
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Your current mark is lower than previous exam');
  }
}
```